# issues with calculation pass band of a Bandpass Filter in Matlab

Tags: matlab

This is a question for a coding class that I am taking. I am creating a bandpass filter in matlab I am supposed to (a) Generate the impulse response of a length-25 bandpass filter with ˆωc = 0.2π, and plot h[n] with a
stem plot.
(b) Compute the frequency response of the length-25 BPF from the previous part and plot its magnitude
and phase versus ˆω over the range −2π ≤ ˆω ≤ 2π.
(c) Use the magnitude response plot to describe the passband of the BPF. For example, measure the
bandwidth at a convenient point such as 50% of the peak.

I have everything working from A-B but not C I have my equation all set up and it should be working but for some reason every time I go to run my program I get my Magnitude and Phase Response plots but the calculation I programmed to calculate the passband of the BPF returns a calculation of zero.

What is supposed to happen is it is supposed to return an actual calculation not a zero. so I don't know what mistake I made and am unable to figure it out. Any help is appreciated as always!

Here is my code

```
L = 25;
wc = 0.2 * pi;

n = 0:L-1;
h = (2/L) * cos(wc*n);

figure;
stem(n, h);
title('Impulse Response h[n]');
xlabel('n');
ylabel('Amplitude');
grid on;

ww = -pi:(pi/1000):pi;
H = freqz(h,1, ww);
%H = fftshift(H);
w = linspace(0, pi, 512);

figure;
subplot(2, 1, 1);
plot(ww, abs(H));
title('Magnitude Response');
xlabel('Frequency (rad/sample)');
ylabel('|H(e^jw)|');
grid on;

subplot(2, 1, 2);
plot(ww, angle(H));
title('Phase Response');
xlabel('Frequency (rad/sample)');
ylabel('<H(e^jw)');
grid on;

peak = max(abs(H));

half_peak_indices = find(abs(H)) >= peak/sqrt (2);
bandwidth = w(half_peak_indices(end)) - w(half_peak_indices(1));

fprintf('The Bandwidth of the BPF at 50%% of the peak is approximately %.3f rad/sample.\n', bandwidth);
```